# От куда берётся лишний вызов? В react при использование react-query и zustand

Tags: reactjs, axios, zustand

Решил для своих тестов сделать небольшое приложение Todo list с использованием react-query и zustand. Все работает хорошо но возникли вопросики по дополнительному вызову компонента Todolist.jsx внутри него я использую

```
const { data: response, isLoading, isError, error } = useFetchTodo();
const data = response?.data;
```

Получаю все что мне необходимо для работы, так-же я имею компонент TodoPagination.jsx который содержит 2 кнопки, назад и далее, для пагинации для них была сделана отдельная функция в zustand

```
const { incrementPage, decrementPage, page, limit, totalCount } = useStoreTodoPagination();
```

Вот сам хук моего store

```
export const useStoreTodoPagination = create(persist((set) => ({
    page: 1,
    limit: 5,
    totalCount: 7, // Временное значение

    setPage: (value) => set({ page: value }),
    incrementPage: () => set(state => ({ page: state.page + 1 })),
    decrementPage: () => set(state => ({ page: state.page - 1 })),
    setLimit: (value) => set({ limit: value }),
    setTotalCount: (value) => set({ totalCount: value }),
}), {
    name: "x-total-count-todo-list"
}));
```

А так-же мой хук запроса useQuery

```
export function useFetchTodo() {
    const filter = useStoreTodoFilter(state => state.filter);
    const search = useStoreTodoSearch(state => state.search);
    const { page, limit, setTotalCount } = useStoreTodoPagination();

    console.log('useFetchTodo');

    return useQuery(['todo-list', filter, search, page, limit], async () =>
        await fetchTodo(filter, search, page, limit),
        {
            keepPreviousData: true,
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            retry: 1,
            onSuccess: (response) => {
                //setTotalCount(parseInt(response.headers.get('x-total-count')));
            }
        });

};
```

Так вот я ни как не могу понять, от куда берется лишний вызов, при нажатие на кнопку мы меняем page что естественно отлавливает хук useFetchTodo, и запускает запрос, это 1 вызов компонента TodoList.jsx потом он заканчивает получает ответ от сервера это 2 вызов что Логично и понятно но откуда еще один?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как описано на картинке, 1 вызов понятно, 2 хз от куда, он появляется сразу, а 3 после ответа, сейчас там стоит задержка.

Фулл код можете посмотреть на [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nice-http-ftdffm?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapi%2FapiTodo.js&embed=1&showConsole=true&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohd96z40007356ibd46qjna%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohd96z40003356i2mfu1681%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohd96z40005356i6auoqlzq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohd96z40006356ivymxxdg4%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clohd96z40003356i2mfu1681%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohd96z40003356i2mfu1681%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clohddiz3009g356ixaqhzcr1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohd96z40002356i22ovclkb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpackage.json%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohdcev70040356ibhpveywt%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapi%252FapiTodo.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohddiz3009g356ixaqhzcr1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstore%252FuseStoreTodo.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohdmuw201c5356i3od894n3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcompontents%252FTodoListItem.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohdnlba01ii356i1hfrlw88%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcompontents%252FTodoPagination.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohdpg8r01tn356idx09hask%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fquery%252FuseQueryTodo.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohdt8gh006u356iwjlbf7x0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clohd96z40006356ivymxxdg4%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohd96z40006356ivymxxdg4%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clohdcl47006s356i34qdvlej%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohdcl47006s356i34qdvlej%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clohd96z40005356i6auoqlzq%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohd96z40005356i6auoqlzq%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clohd9tiq00ac356i63swa9do%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohd96z40004356iqiql9ki5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clohdbppf000wedipcgvxdgo5%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohd9tiq00ac356i63swa9do%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) Можете открыть ссылку, после загрузки очистить консоль(чтобы не запутаться) и перейти на другую страницу, чтобы увидеть что происходит.

Comment: [Не это?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1405415/178988)

Comment: Но у меня нету useEffect() :) для хранения и обновления состояния я использовал библиотеку zustand. И так-же React.StrictMode нету!